# Make PHPBB 3.0.14 and ABBC3 compatible with PHP 7.3

Tags: php, phpbb

I'm trying to make ABBC3 work with PHP 7.3 and PHPBB 3.0.14 since I can't move to PHPBB 3.3 due lots of issues with MODs not ported to extensions and theme (Absolution).

I have asked help in [PHPBB forum](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=15372731) without luck because 3.0.x and 3.1.x version are not supported anymore.

So after dozens of hours trying to understand bbcode functions I'm almost ready.

My code works when there's a single bbcode in message. But doesn't works when there's more bbcode or it's mixed with texts.

So I would like to get some help to solve this part to make everything work.

In line 98 in [includes/bbcode.php](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/3.0.x/phpBB/includes/bbcode.php#L98) this function:

`$message = preg_replace($preg['search'], $preg['replace'], $message);`

Is returning something like this:

`$message = "some text $this->Text_effect_pass('glow', 'red', 'abc') another text. $this->moderator_pass('"fernando"', 'hello!') more text"`

For this message:

> some text [glow=red]abc[/glow] another text.
>
> [mod="fernando"]hello![/mod] more text

The input for **preg_replace** above is like this just for context:

`"some text [glow=red:mkpanc3g]abc[/glow:mkpanc3g] another text. [mod="fernando":mkpanc3g]hello![/mod:mkpanc3g]"`

So basically I have to split this string in valid expressions to apply **eval()** then concatenate everything. Like this:

```
$message = "some text". eval($this->Text_effect_pass('glow', 'red', 'abc');) . "another text " . eval($this->moderator_pass('"fernando"', 'hello!');). "more text"
```

In this specific case there's also double quotes left in **'"fernando"'**.

I know is not safe apply **eval()** to user input so I would like to make  some type of **preg_match** and/or **preg_split** to get values inside of **()** to pass as parameter to my functions.

The functions are basically:

```
Text_effect_pass()
moderator_pass()
anchor_pass()
simpleTabs_pass()
```

I'm thinking in something like this (Please ignore errors here):

```
if(preg_match("/$this->Text_effect_pass/", $message)
{
 then split the string and get value inside of() and remove extra single or double quotes.


 after:
 $textEffect = Text_effect_pass($value[0], $value[1], $value[2]);

 Finally concatenate everything:
 $message = $string[0] .$textEffect. $string[1]; 
}
if(preg_match("/$this->moderator_pass/", $message)
{
.....
}
```

P.S.: ABBC3 is not compatible with PHP 7.3 due usage of **e** modifier. I have edited everything to remove the modifier.

Here you can see it working separately:

[bbcode 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD4gj.png)

[bbcode 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhbaQ.png)

Can someone give me some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time searching for a solution for this problem I found this [site](http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3) that helped me build the regex.

Now I have managed to solve the problem and I have my forum fully working with PHPBB 3.14, PHP 7.3 and ABBC3.

My solution is:

```
// Start Text_effect_pass
$regex = "/(\\$)(this->Text_effect_pass)(\().*?(\')(,)( )(\').*?(\')(,)( )(\').*?(\'\))/is";

if (preg_match_all($regex, $message, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $func) {
                $bracket = preg_split("/(\\$)(this->Text_effect_pass)/", $func);
                $param = explode("', '", $bracket[1]);
                $param[0] = substr($param[0], 2);
                $param[2] = substr($param[2], 0, strrpos($param[2], "')"));
                $effect = $this->Text_effect_pass($param[0], $param[1], $param[2]);
                if ($key == 0) {
                        $init = $message;
                } else {
                        $init = $mess;
                }
                $mess = str_replace($matches[0][$key], $effect, $init);
        }
        $message = $mess;
} // End Text_effect_pass

// Start moderator_pass
$regex = "/(\\$)(this->moderator_pass)(\().*?(\')(,).*?(\').*?(\'\))/is";

if (preg_match_all($regex, $message, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $func) {
                $bracket = "/(\\$)(this->moderator_pass)/";
                $bracket = preg_split($bracket, $func);
                $param = explode("', '", $bracket[1]);
                $param[0] = substr($param[0], 2);
                $param[1] = substr($param[1], 0, strrpos($param[1], "')"));

                $effect = $this->moderator_pass($param[0], $param[1]);
                if ($key == 0) {
                        $init = $message;
                } else {
                        $init = $mess;
                }
                $mess = str_replace($matches[0][$key], $effect, $init);
        }
        $message = $mess;
} // End moderator_pass
```

If someone is interested can find patch files and instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/FernandoGarcia/4219f0530986fbbfcfb39c9ed1695489).

Best regards.